# How can I create an AWS ec2 instance clone for redesigning website using a separate domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

My current ec2 instance is running original website using abc.com I have cloned the instance by saving an image and launched it as a new instance. I want to open it using a separate domain i.e. xyz.com.

I have pointed A record of xyz.com to the IP of the new instance. Now the new domain name redirects to the original website abc.com. I think this is happening because the old wordpress website redirects to the original domain.

I tried accessing the database of new instance but i am unable to do so. Can anyone help me with this? I have working Putty and Filezilla.

Comment: You should probably ask this question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you created a clone using AMI.  That's good.  You pointed the A recocd of new domain ,`xyz.com`, to cloned server, also good.

When you go to `xyz.com`, you somehow get redirectod to `abc.com`, and this is a problem.

When you created the AMI, you created an *exact*, bit-for-bit copy of the original server.  So, if the original server is somewhere doing a redirect, then so is your clone.

You need to edit the application code on the clone to redirect to `xyz.com` rather than `abc.com`.

I don't know how Wordpress works, so I can't offer any insighrs on that front, but that's what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, simply go to Settings » General from your WordPress admin panel. After that, enter your new domain under the ‘Site Address (URL)’ field.

[Add Site Address URL in Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cOkG.png)